# Provide a testing implementation of a monad stack

Tags: haskell

Here's a constructed monad stack in my program:

```
type Px a = ReaderT PConf (State PState) a
```

Where PConf and PState are arbitrary data types holding the configuration and the state of the app.

I need to provide a default implementation so i can test my functions, given a 'PConf' and a 'PState':

```
p4 :: Px ()
p4 = ???
  where
    conf  = PConf 4 10 10 [0, 1]
    state = PState 0 0 $ M.fromList [((x, y), Nothing) | x <- [0..9], y <- [0..9]]
```

I don't know what to write in "p4 = " so that the implementation uses 'conf' and 'state'.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `p4` is a `Px ()` action, then that is *not* the point you define the `conf` to pass in, and if `state` is supposed to be the initial state, not that one either. Instead you should put those in the function that *tests* `p4`:

```
p4 :: Px ()
p4 = ...

test = runState (runReaderT p4 conf) state
  where
    conf  = PConf 4 10 10 [0, 1]
    state = PState 0 0 $ M.fromList [((x, y), Nothing) | x <- [0..9], y <- [0..9]]
```

EDIT: In case your problem is still with writing `p4` itself, here's a small mockup `p4` that changes some of the state to contain some of the original `conf`:

```
p4 = do
   PConf x y z _ <- ask
   PState m n mp <- get
   put $ PState m n (M.insert (x, y) (Just z) mp)
```